# I have troubles during using importexcel on powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I couldn't find anything about a problem importing excel in the WEB.

[image]

Why doesn't my Powershell give output like you? Please help me?

Comment: `$bare | Format-Table`

Comment: Thank you bro. How cant i think this!  Besides why doesnt anybody mention from format-table when they tell the import excel.                                                            
Also i suggest to everybody who doesnt know anything about open-excelpackage to search it. It makes easier to get values from the cells.